# How to Release memory while using librosa

Tags: python-3.x, memory-leaks, ram, librosa

I use librosa to load and pyin a wav file, but it can't be release all the memory which librosa used, how can I release all this memory? my python is 3.6.8, my librosa version is 0.8.1.

1.5 MiB and 50.7 MiB can't be release. and my system mem usage will become bigger

| Line# | Mem usage | Increment | Occurences | Line Contents |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 196 | 641.1 MiB | 1.5 MiB | 1 | y, sr = librosa.load(filepath, sr=None, mono=True) |
| 199 | 691.8 MiB | 50.7 MiB | 1 | f0 = librosa.yin(y, fmin=librosa.note_to_hz('D2'), fmax=librosa.note_to_hz('D6'), sr=sr) |

Comment: I have try to del y but memory still leak.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example